# get all the options selected of a multiple select without jQuery

Tags: javascript

I would like to get back all the option selected of a multiple select when i submit my form.

like :

```
<select id="multipleSelect" multiple="multiple">
<option value="1">Text 1</option>
<option value="2">Text 2</option>
<option value="3">Text 3</option>
```

using somthing like that :

```
var selectedValues = document.getElementbyId('multipleSelect).values;
```

and get an array with all the value selected like ['2','3']

All that, without jQuery and in js or php is fine :)

thx!

Comment: lulz, i know :)

I tried `document.getElementbyId('multipleSelect).value`, but i only get 1 option (even when i selected more) ...

I tried somthing with `foreach ($_GET['selectid'] as $selectedOption)`
but doesn't worked...

I just searching for something like the `.val()` in jquery, but in only js...

Comment: @Crocsx server-side `=/=` client-side

Comment: missing to close `'` and it is `value` here `getElementbyId('multipleSelect).values;`

Comment: i know it's value ^^ but it return only 1 option, so i writed s to make understand that i'm searching for somthing who give values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var options = document.getElementById('multipleSelect').options,
    result = [];

for (var i = 0, len = options.length; i < len; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];

    if (opt.selected) {
        result.push(opt.value);
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/AH2yK/

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
var options = document.getElementById('multipleSelect').options;
var values = [];
var i = 0, len = options.length;

while (i < len)
{
    if(options[i].selected){
     values.push(options[i].value);        
    }
    i++;
}
alert(values.join(', '));
```